# JSGrid, I want to fill one field type select when I select one item from another select, Example Country - States

Tags: select, autofill, jsgrid

In JSGRID, I want to fill one select field with some values when I select one value from another select inthe same row. Example I select one Country and inmediately the next field (select type) fills with the states relatives to that Country.

Concrete answers from JSGRID community.